# I'm trying to plot the confusion matrix for the predictions on my test set using my neural network model, but this error keeps on popping out

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to plot the confusion matrix for the predictions on my test set using my neural network model, but this error keeps on popping out. Can you please help me out. I tried to clicked the search on stackoverflow, but I didn't get a definitive answer. Can someone please help me out to resolve this error and pinpoint what error I have made? Also, if possible, what suggestions can you give? Thank you so much. [Here is the picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8V1I.jpg) and [this is my actual work](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NdpWmOVbqV2EUJ50vLj7nhWdWWHtbY_8?usp=sharing)

This is the code:
cm_plot_labels=['adobong baboy',  'arroz caldo','bagnet','balut','bicol express','biko' ,'binignit','bulalo','caldereta','camaro rebusado','champorado',
'chicharon','chicken inasal','cooked white rice','fish kinilaw','halo halo','liempo','maja blanca','pancit habhab', 'pandesal', 'pastillas de leche','pichi pichi',
'puto bumbong','puto rice cake','rellenong alimango','sinugno','sisig','suman','tapa','tinola','tuna panga','turon','ube halaya' ]
plot_confusion_matrix(cm=cm, classes=cm_plot_labels, title='Confusion Matrix')

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, `'plt.cm.Blues'` is not a valid value for the cmap argument of the `plt.imshow` function. The error suggests possible valid values that can be passed as the cmap value.

So, to solve your error you should be able to just set the default value of cmap in the `plot_confusion_matrix` function parameters to the string value `'Blues'` instead of `'plt.cm.Blues'`.

Here is the documentation for the `plt.imshow` function which you are using. Here it gives details of what the parameters are (including cmap) and what valid values can be passed to them.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Comment: i already change plot_confusion_matrix function parameters to the string value 'Blues' but the same error still appears

Comment: Passing `'Blues'` to the `cmap` parameter of the `plt.imshow` function solved the error. Alternatively you can set `cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')` for example. Both of these solved this error for me. NOTE: After solving this error there was a different error, `np.arrange` should be `np.arange` when generating `tick_marks` in `plot_confusion_matrix`.